# QObject::connect: No such signal

Tags: c++, qt

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему не удаётся подсоединить слот setNum(int) к сигналу countChanged(int)?
Что примечательно, при попытке изменить название сигнала ext() (разумеется, с изменением во всём файле) он тоже перестаёт подключаться. Я правда не понимаю.

```
#include <QtWidgets>
#include <QApplication>

using namespace std;


class Counter : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
private:
    int count;

public:
    Counter() : count(0) {}

public slots:
    void incSlot()
    {
        count++;
        emit countChanged(count);
        if(count >= 5)
            emit ext();
    }

signals:
    void ext();
    void countChanged(int);
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QLabel lbl("0");
    QPushButton cmd("ADD");
    Counter counter;

    lbl.show();
    cmd.show();

    QObject::connect(&cmd, SIGNAL(clicked()),
                     &counter, SLOT(incSlot()));

    QObject::connect(&counter, SIGNAL(countChanged(int)),
                     &lbl, SLOT(setNum(int)));

    QObject::connect(&counter, SIGNAL(ext()),
                     &app, SLOT(quit()));

    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: Перенесите определение `Counter` в *.h  файл, либо добавьте `#include "main.moc"` в конце main.cpp.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41614016/define-a-qobject-derived-class-inside-an-anonymous-namespace

Comment: Благодарю, это (перенос в отдельный файл) действительно решило проблему. Не знал о таких нюансах. Впрочем, вариант с main.moc в конце не сработал (не видит этот файл), но вы скинули ссылку, так что я смогу лучше ознакомиться с вопросом.